# PHPUnit multiple mocked methods of the same name

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm wondering how to go about testing this. Say I have a getter method, and I change the value in the process of a method. Here's a simple example:

```
public function foo($model)
{
  var_dump($model->state());
  $model->state('saved');
  var_dump($model->state());
}
```

I mock the model like so:

```
$model = $this->getMock('Model');
$model->expects($this->any))
  ->method('state')
  ->will($this->returnValue('new'));
```

How should I setup the mock so that the second call returns a different value (saved)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$model = $this->getMock('Model');
$model->expects($this->at(0))
  ->method('state')
  ->will($this->returnValue('new'));
$model->expects($this->at(1))
  ->method('state')
  ->will($this->returnValue('saved'));
$model->expects($this->exactly(2))
  ->method('state');
```

http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects

Plus you can additionally check with `with()` that the parameter passed equals to `saved`

```
->with($this->equalTo('saved'))
```

PS: this will work for

```
public function foo($model)
{
  var_dump($model->state());
  var_dump($model->state('saved'));
}
```

For your code you need to set up 3 mock calls, not 2

Comment: IIRC `equalTo` is the default if you pass a bare value so you can use `with('saved')`. At least I hope that's the case because we do that a lot. :)

Comment: @David Harkness: yep, I also use it in 50/50, because hadn't time yet to sit and check the real difference ;-)

Answer (score 3):

With [Mockery](https://github.com/padraic/mockery), which integrates with PHPUnit but is a far superior mocking library, you would write it like this:

```
$model = m::mock('model');
$model->shouldReceive('state')->andReturn($returnValue, $differentReturnValue);
```

It is obvious how much more beautiful the Mockery API is. It's an ode to readable code. It reads like text...

> model should receive state and return values

You can add a constraint that the method has to be called exactly twice like so:

```
$model->shouldReceive('state')->twice()->andReturn($value, $differentValue);
```

If you want to pass arguments, it looks like this:

```
$model->shouldReceive('state')->withNoArgs()->andReturn($value)->once();
$model->shouldReceive('state')->with('saved')->andReturn($differentValue)->once();
```

Comment: Just curious - how to specify that in first call there should be no arguments to `state` passed and that in second call the argument should be equal to `saved`?

Comment: PHPUnit tends to use methods that accept arguments created using methods on the test case, requiring a lot of `$this->`. I wrote simple helper methods to avoid this to make the API read more like English, similar to what Mockery does, e.g. `$mock->expect('foo')->once()->willReturn('bar')`. The end result is the same, but it improves readibility.